# Load custom font in actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to display "Hello World" with calibri.ttf using only AC3. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you need to embed the font in your FLA.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure AS3 you can use the [embed] tag. Here's a straight forward example from Tink : http://www.tink.ws/blog/embedding-fonts-in-as3/